# On an average, space of how many economy class seats is taken up by a suite?

Tags: aircraft-design, commercial-aviation, airline-operations, cost

The suites offered by many airlines for the super rich, are very spacious and convenient. Though, I can only [Read](http://m.businessinsider.in/10-First-Class-Airplane-Seats-That-Are-Nicer-Than-Your-Apartment/articleshow/35034905.cms) about them! One thing I can see is, the A380 is capable of upto 853 economy only passengers, but most of them carry 500 economy, 65 business and 12 suites. So, they must be eating some considerable amount of space. What I am asking is, basically the number of economy class seats that would fit inside a first class cabin and not how much space is available for first class and economy class cabins.

Comment: [If this is not a duplicate...] I'm in favor of moving it to [Travel:SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com), as suggested in the possible duplicate by Pondlife.

Comment: The super rich travel in their own jets, you just mean regular, not filthy rich.

Answer (score 3):

The size of the seat is slightly different in each airline, but according to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A380_seat_configurations), 32"×18" is the smallest, and most common, economy seat. That is 4 ft².

According to the article you linked, the largest suite is 125 ft². That is 31¼ times more.

Remember, however, that space is not the only consideration. The main consideration for aircraft is *weight* and obviously first class passenger does not weigh more than economy class one.

Now consider that those 853 passengers, with baggage, will weight around 80 t. Maximum take-off weight is 575 t of which 276 t is empty weight and the tanks can take about 260 t of fuel. But that leaves you only 39 t for payload with full tanks! So on very long routes, the aircraft *can't* pack 853 passengers anyway. The 500 is about maximum that makes sense (for long range variant, which is most common).

So they don't mind wasting some space for luxurious first class if they can charge premium for it.

Comment: "and obviously first class passenger does not weigh more than economy class one." the suite itself probablly does weigh more than an economy class seat though.